# Amazon MWS: getting error 99019 for XML productFeeds (SubmitFeed of type _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_)

Tags: amazon-mws

When I try to add a product (via a SubmitFeed of type "_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_") to the Amazon Market via the Amazon MWS API I get the following error:

> [Marketplace : Amazon.de] A valid value is required in either the
>   "quantity" or "fulfillment_center_id" field.

But there is no "quantity" or "fulfillment_center_id" field in my Product.xsd nor in the official documentation. Also the exact same feed does work without an error on my Amazon MWS sandbox account. What am I missing?

Complete XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope>
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>XXX</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>123456</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>EAN</Type>
                <Value>767715012826</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_TAX</ProductTaxCode>
            <Condition>
                <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
                <ConditionNote>Zustand/condition: neu OVP</ConditionNote>
            </Condition>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Bellydance for Fitness and Fun</Title>
                <Manufacturer>New World 2011</Manufacturer>
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
                <Music>
                    <ProductType>
                        <MusicPopular>
                            <MediaType>audioCD</MediaType>
                            <NumberOfDiscs>1</NumberOfDiscs>
                            <Genre>New Age</Genre>
                        </MusicPopular>
                    </ProductType>
                </Music>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure that you use the correct "Merchant Token" (NOT merchant id) in the tag "MerchantIdentifier" inside your feed (this isn't well documented).

   ```
   <MerchantIdentifier>YOUR_MERCHANT_TOKEN</MerchantIdentifier>
   ```

   You should see your Merchant Token by navigating to `Sellercentral > Settings > Account Info` and clicking on `Your Merchant Token` inside the box `Business Information`. If the Merchant Token isn't there (which was a common error in the past), contact the Seller Support and ask for the correct Merchant Token: `Please send me my Merchant Token (NOT merchant id) for use with 3rd party software.`
2. Try to omit additional tags describing the product, especially the whole `<ProductData>` section inside the `<Product>` element. Whenever i specified the `<ProductData>` section I got error 99019.

Comment: can you please share the add product feed working xml

Comment: As of 2022, Sellercentral > Settings > Account Info > Business Information, Your Merchant Token

Answer (score 0):

The field names in MWS error messages do not match the XML structure. I'm assuming they match the flat file (CSV) columns, but haven't actually checked.

You stated "I try to add a product", while I'm guessing that above error happened when subitting an inventory feed, which is why you won't find the anything of that sort in Product.xsd.

The corresponding XML elements are `Quantity` and `FulfillmentCenterID`, both defined in [Inventory.xsd](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/Inventory.xsd).

Comment: the error appeared when i posted a SubmitFeed of type _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_ - it was not an inventory feed.

Comment: And your `<MessageType>` did contain the value `Product` and not `Inventory` ? Just asking, because the requirement of either having a quantity or a fulfillment center id matches the requirements of inventory feeds. My product feeds have neither, and they do get processed without error.

Comment: I have added the submitted feed to my question - the MessageType was "Product". I know that the error message would fit to an Inventory-Feed, but it appeared when i posted a Product-Feed

Comment: Also note that this error seems a bit related to legacy accounts. I didn't get this error when i used another, newly created account.